# How can I repair blown plaster on walls?

Tags: drywall

I live in a very old cottage (1747) some of the plaster mainly on exterior walls has blown/blistered with a powdery residue.  We have hacked off the plaster - treated the walls and re-plastered but slowly it is returning.  What are we not doing that we should be?

Comment: Have you checked for structural damage that may be causing this?

Comment: That could be efflorescence which is caused by moisture migration. Are there moisture issues on the exterior walls?